# How use jade template for HTML?

Tags: node.js, rest, pug

I have Create a simple form that having three buttons. i need that buttons should be in a single row in table format.

Example:

```
<table><tr><td>button1</td><td>button2</td><td>button3</td></tr></table>
```

My Code :

```
table
    tr
        td
            form#formAddUser(name="viewAll",method="get",action="/userlist")        
                button#btnSubmit(type="submit") View All
        td
            form#formAddUser(name="new",method="get",action="/newuser")        
                button#btnSubmit(type="submit") New
        td
            form#formAddUser(name="delete",method="get",action="/delete")        
                button#btnSubmit(type="submit") Delete
```

But it showing error while accessing in browser that "Invalid indentation, you can use tabs or spaces but not both"

Please Help me !

Comment: Which code editor are you using?

Comment: i just edited with text editor in ubuntu . .

Comment: Do you have `vim` editor installed?

Answer (score 0):

This is what `vim` shows me with `:set listchars=eol:$,tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<`:

```
    table$
>------->-------tr$
>------->------->-------td$
>------->------->------->-------form#formAddUser(name="viewAll",method="get",action="/userlist")~~~~~~~~$
        >------->------->-------button#btnSubmit(type="submit") View All$
>------->------->-------td$
>------->------->------->-------form#formAddUser(name="new",method="get",action="/newuser")~~~~~~~~$
>------->------->-------        button#btnSubmit(type="submit") New$
>------->------->-------td$
>------->------->------->-------form#formAddUser(name="delete",method="get",action="/delete")~~~~~~~~$
>------->------->-------        button#btnSubmit(type="submit") Delete$
```

So, now you could understand where is the Tab and where Space is used. I recommend to use sublime or any other editors.

It proper edit it should look like, **Major Edit in Your code was to indent the button inside form**:

```
table$
>------->-------tr$
>------->------->-------td$
>------->------->------->-------form#formAddUser(name="viewAll",method="get",action="/userlist")$
>------->------->------->------->-------button#btnSubmit(type="submit") View All$
>------->------->-------td$
>------->------->------->-------form#formAddUser(name="new",method="get",action="/newuser")$
>------->------->------->------->-------button#btnSubmit(type="submit") New$
>------->------->-------td$
>------->------->------->-------form#formAddUser(name="delete",method="get",action="/delete")$
>------->------->------->------->-------button#btnSubmit(type="submit") Delete$
```

---

If you want to see the same in `gedit` i.e Ubuntu's Text Editor, Then check there is a ***[gedit-plugins](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/gedit-plugins)*** package available. Install that and take a look at the ***Draw Spaces*** section in the `gedit` preferences. You can configure it to show white spaces, tabs, line feeds etc.

---

**Update:** Below is the HTML sent to client

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form action="/userlist" id="formAddUser" method="get" name=
            "viewAll">
                <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">View All</button>
            </form>
        </td>

        <td>
            <form action="/newuser" id="formAddUser" method="get" name=
            "new">
                <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">New</button>
            </form>
        </td>

        <td>
            <form action="/delete" id="formAddUser" method="get" name=
            "delete">
                <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Code share:**

1. [./package.json](http://codeshare.io/J0l36)
2. [./app.js](http://codeshare.io/ygFE8)
3. [./views/index.jade](http://codeshare.io/7YHnW)

Do a `npm install` and hit `http://127.0.0.1:3000`

Comment: Even using vim, i can't resolve this problem guys. .  Can anyone give me the code for the above example. . ?

Comment: Each td should contain a form and a button. .

Comment: @RajeevUlaganathan: As highlighted above, you should remove `trail` i.e. `~` & white spaces. I will update same in my answer..

Comment: Can you tell me the shared code is working for you? And you should use one white space **or** a tab for each level of indentation(in above example I had used tab)

Comment: Oh . .  i just picked that code from html to jade converter site. . and its working fine . .  also thank u so much for your response . .